# Класс DbContext в entify framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp-net-core-mvc

зачем нужен этот класс? не понятно из описания. я проектирую asp .net mvc веб приложение. изучая фреймворк.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DbContext - общий класс для работы с базой данных. Контекстов может быть несколько, но чаще всего используют один. В DbContext вы **можете** указать:

1. Ваши сущности базы данных через DbSet.
2. Дополнительные настройки сущностей и самой базы данных через FluentAPI. Например, можно заполнить некие таблицы значениями по умолчанию или настроить ForeignKey для сущностей, правила каскадного удаления и.т.п
3. Правила подключения к базе данных
4. И много чего другого

Comment: Но всё же рекомендуется оставить в классе `DbContext` только `DbSet` определения таблиц - а всё остальное выносить в отдельные классы, например классы конфигурации `<EntityName>Configuration` через флюент. Чтобы класс не становился классом-богом.

Comment: @AK, что прочитать про  fluent посоветуешь?

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к ответу @Lapish, `DbContext` реализует важный паттерн Unit of Work.

Изменения, сделанные вами в DbContext, либо попадают в базу полностью при вызове `SaveChanges[Async]`, либо не попадают тоже полностью. Таким образом, если вы начали какие-то изменения, и в процессе работы *что-то пошло не так*, то вы просто можете бросить исключение, не вызывать `SaveChanges`, и изменения не будут отражены в базе данных. Таким образом, ваша база будет всё время в консистентном состоянии.